# Firebase push notification (android+ node.js)

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, firebase

Is it possible to save FCM generated token in mysql database? I have node.js api server (node.js + express) with registration/authentication (using JWT) which is deploing to heroku. I need to add in my android app opportunity to send push notification. Is it possible save fcm token in my existing mysql db without using firebase realtime db.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

But you need create some web services.

When a device with your app start and call the firebase register url the id/token is generated, your app need send this token to a Data Base using a web service.

Then to send a push notification to these device you can call  an other web service who recover the token from ypur Data Base to send the push notification

Comment: thank you for your answer, what web services do you mean ?

Comment: A primitive web service can be a url who receive parameters using a GET method, http://yourdomain.com/webservice?token=4DFHWDF734HY8F4H&id=Mike Device. With NodeJS you can create a REST Web service using JSON